# How choose the right serializer depends on specific field ? e.g. type

Tags: django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I'd like to serialize an input from an API to check if the format is valid

```
ProfileSerializer(payload).is_valid()
```

`profile.py`

```
from rest_framework import serializers

from .node import NodeSerializer

class ProfileSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    node = NodeSerializer(many=True)
```

`node.py`

```
from rest_framework import serializers

from .point import PointSerializer

class NodeSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    id = serializers.IntegerField()
    points = PointSerializer(many=True)
    type = serializers.CharField(max_length=50)
```

The issue is the `node` format, depend on the `type` -> `SEGMENT, ARC, ...` I need to select the right serializer.

So I create a serializer for each type `type` -> `SEGMENT, ARC, ...` but I can't figure out how to use them inside the `ProfileSerializer`.

How can I catch the type field and use it inside a provider parser function

I'd like to make something like this:

`node_serializer_provider.py`

```
from commons.interfaces.object_factory import ObjectFactory
from enum import Enum
from central.serializers.fao.node import SegmentSerializer
from central.serializers.fao.node import FilletSerializer
from central.serializers.fao.node import ThreadSerializer

class NodeEnum(Enum):
    SEGMENT="SEGMENT"
    FILLET = "FILLET"
    THREAD = "THREAD"

class NodeSerializerProvider(ObjectFactory):
    def get(self, tool_type, **kwargs):
        return self.create(tool_type, **kwargs)
    
services = NodeSerializerProvider()
services.register_builder(NodeEnum.SEGMENT.value, SegmentSerializer)
services.register_builder(NodeEnum.FILLET.value, FilletSerializer)
services.register_builder(NodeEnum.THREAD.value, ThreadSerializer)
```

`profile.py`

```
from rest_framework import serializers

from central.services import node_serializer_provider


class ProfileSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    # TODO find a way to extract the field type and call the provider
    nodes = node_serializer_provider.services.get("TYPE", **{many=True})
```

### EDIT

I tried the second solution of @Ken4scholars to use the SerializerMethodField:

Inside my view I get a request data and I want to check if data send is well format.

```
@action(detail=False, methods=['post'])
def retrieve(self, request):
    
    serializer = ReportSerializer(data=request.data)
    is_ok = serializer.is_valid()
```

Here the ReportSerializer

```
from rest_framework import serializers

from .profile import ProfileSerializer
from .workpiece import WorkpieceSerializer

class ReportSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    profile = ProfileSerializer()
    unit = serializers.CharField(max_length=2)
    workpiece = WorkpieceSerializer()
    ...
```

.

```
class ProfileSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    nodes = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_nodes(self, instance):
        data = [] 
        for n in instance["nodes"]:
            serializer = services.get(n["type"], **{"data": n})
            serializer.is_valid()
            if serializer.errors:
                pass
                # Raise an error
            data.append(serializer.data)
        return data
```

But I got the KeyError nodes doesn't exist... and when I print the `instance` I got an empty `OrderedDict`

Even with a simple case like this:

```
{ #get from the api
  "profile": {
    "ok": {"some_field": "some_value"}
  }
}
```

.

```
ok = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
def get_ok(self, obj):
    print(obj) # get an empty OrderedDict
    return "get_ok"
```

Comment: How do you initialize the profile serilializer? As I mentioned in my answer, the SerializerMethodField is read_only. So you can't use it to accept data, only serialize Python objects to dictionary and not from dictionary to Python objects. If indeed you are serializing and not taking input, then you son't need serializer.is_valid()

Comment: post the code where you create ProfileSerializer(...) object

Comment: I updated the question, In my case, I'll get a payload from an api and I want to check if this payload (json) is well format with the ReportSerializer(data=payload).is_valid().

Comment: Now I see. Then SerilaizerMethodField won't help as it is read-only. So it is useful for serializing python objects into dictionaries and not the other way round. Try the first option then

Answer (score 0):

You can approach it in different ways:

1. make a base ProfileSerializer and then separate child classes that just override the node field, providing the right serializer. This way, you wouldn't need the factory:

```
class BaseProfileSerializer(serializer.Serializer):
    ...
    node = None

class SegmentProfileSerializer(BaseProfileSerializer):
    node = SegmentSerializer(many=True)

class FilletProfileSerializer(BaseProfileSerializer):
    node = FilletSerializer(many=True)

class ThreadProfileSerializer(BaseProfileSerializer):
    node = ThreadSerializer(many=True)
```

Then use the appropriate serializer.

2. Use the SerializerMethodField() - this option is probably the neatest and simplest

```
NODE_SERIALIZER_MAP = {'SEGMENT' SegmentSerializer, 'FILET': FilerSerializer, 'THREAD': ThreadSerializer}
class ProfileSerializer(serializer.Serializer):
    ...
    node = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_node(self, instance):
        serializer_class = NODE_SERIALIZER_MAP.get(instance.node_type)
        serializer = serializer_class(instance.nodes, many=True, context=self.context)
        return serializer.data()
```

Of course, I am assuming you're not using it to accept input, but serialize and return output. The node field name should also be changed to use the proper name.

Comment: Thanks for you answer ! For my case I have to use the second alternative. I try with the SerializerMethodField() and when I try to acces to some field I got an issue KeyError

Example json ->   "profile": {"ok": {"some_field": "some_value"}}
    # inside the ProfileSerializer
    def get_ok(self, instance):
        print(instance["some_field"])
        return "get_ok"

Raise a Exception Type: KeyError some_field